# getting error in simple .first(), .count() in pyspark,

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i am running following code on windows10 jupyter notebook,

```
airline= 'C:\spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7\airlines.csv'
airlines = sc.textFile(airline)
print(airlines)
```

> > C:\spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7irlines.csv MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0

(this gives me proper output )

when i try to run `print(airlines.first())`
i am getting error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-36bc0976264b> in <module>
----> 1 print(airlines.first())
.
.
.
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7irlines.csv
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.partitions$(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What is `sc` here ?

Comment: Spark is lazy. This means the file will not be loaded until it is needed. Therefore your first statement does not cause any errors, it does not load the file. Once you call `collect`, `first`, `toPandas`, `show` or any other "Action", the required "Transformations" will be executed, such as `sc.textFile`. The error is simply stating that your file does not exist on given input path. Looks easy to solve!

Comment: @akshat, sc is default for the spark context object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume input path provided by you is correct. If not you have to review it. Further do following corrections in your code:

Instead of:

```
airline= 'C:\spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7\airlines.csv'
```

write as follows:

```
airline= 'C:\\spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7\\airlines.csv'
```

(or)

```
airline= 'C:/spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7/airlines.csv'
```

Instead of:

```
print(airlines)
```

write as follows:

```
   for i in airline.take(10): print (i)
```

(or)

```
   for i in airline.collect(): print (i)
```

Note: Use collect() only if your file size is small else use take(n) where n is integer number.

Comment: Thank you Sri_Karthik,
making ( double \\) helped me

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment so I must ask this simple questions using an answer:

are you sure the path you have written in the variable is correct? Looking at the message it doesn't seem so:

`..hadoop2.7irlines.csv` <== "`/ai`" is missing?